# GIT Как правильно оформить несколько проектов в одном репозитории

Tags: git, git-branch

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть у меня [репозиторий на git](https://github.com/exp0rs/Hello-World) и несколько написанных проектов на React - хочу загрузить их в одну папку. Возможно ли чтобы **для каждого** из проектов **в этой папке** была **своя ветка/дерево** или для каждого проекта необходимо заводить отдельный ропозиторий? Как правильно и как принято?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильнее сделать для каждого проекта отдельный репозиторий. Если требуется совместное использование проектов, то можно использовать механизмы подмодулей ([submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8)) или поддеревье ([subtree](https://habr.com/ru/post/429014/)), в этом случае один репозиторий становится частью другого.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679614/whats-the-best-practice-for-putting-multiple-projects-in-a-git-repository  а как же orphan?

Comment: Это будут отдельно висящие гирлянды коммитов. Работать с этим будет не просто. Я таких примеров в жизни не видел. С подмодулями как-то надежнее. Ответ немного поправил. Спасибо.